# How to see all the possible Null pointer exception lints in my code?

Tags: android, android-studio

I use both Kotlin and Java in my code, because of the Kotlin's flexible nullability, I get `method invocation ... may produce java.lang.NullPointerException` lints in my code,

I run `Code inspection` in my project, it displays

- Android Lint: Accessibility
- Android Lint: Correctness
- Android Lint: Internationalization
- Android Lint: Performance

and

- Android Lint: Usability

none of them lists the possible NPE lints? Is there a place to list those lints?

Answer (score 5):

I just realized when you inspect code in Android Studio there is a section called **`Probable bugs`**

under this section there is **`Constant conditions & exceptions`**

and it displays all the NPE lints, not specifically for NPE but it may help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You might use [Null Away](https://github.com/uber/NullAway) which is a tool created by Uber's development team. It will help you find the possible NPE in your code at the cost of a little configuration in your code.

> NullAway is a tool to help eliminate NullPointerExceptions (NPEs) in your Java code. To use NullAway, first add @Nullable annotations in your code wherever a field, method parameter, or return value may be null. Given these annotations, NullAway performs a series of type-based, local checks to ensure that any pointer that gets dereferenced in your code cannot be null. NullAway is similar to the type-based nullability checking in the Kotlin and Swift languages, and the Checker Framework and Eradicate null checkers for Java.
>
> NullAway is fast. It is built as a plugin to Error Prone and can run on every single build of your code. In our measurements, the build-time overhead of running NullAway is usually less than 10%. NullAway is also practical: it does not prevent all possible NPEs in your code, but it catches most of the NPEs we have observed in production while imposing a reasonable annotation burden, giving a great "bang for your buck." At Uber, we combine NullAway with RAVE to obtain thorough protection against NPEs in our Android apps.

Keep it mind that it will only help you find NPE, it does not guarantee that you won't get any.

I hope this will help you,
Regards,
Matthieu

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good analyzer tool from facebook called [infer](http://fbinfer.com/) which do a very good job in not only finding NPE but other errors like resource leak, race conditions etc.

Comment: See if this helps, actually it is not very difficult to include infer in android
http://fbinfer.com/docs/hello-world.html#hello-world-android

Comment: Thanks. Their quickstart guide is so bad because they don't mention the dependencies you need to run infer, for example `opam, python, sqlite, autoconf or automake...or even homebrew`, their guide is like step1: install infer and step2: use it

Comment: FYI: If your project contains Kotlin like mine, you'll get an error. Infer supports only C, Python, Objective-C and Java

Comment: Oh thanks for the info, I didn't know this. But since Kotlin is also a JVM based language, I think Infer should support Kotlin also. Can you raise this question in infer gtihub repo?